# Como incluir un archivo css ó js. trabajo desde yiiframework2 basic. Como crear el link desde la carpeta web?

Tags: php, yii2

Al anexar el archivo .css uso el @web.Archivo que se encuentra ubicado en la  carpeta de  web/css .no esta funcionando en la vista.

```
**<link rel="stylesheet" href="@web/css/miestilo.css">**
```

dentro del head del html. alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: En el código fuente  generado, qué valor resulta de `@web/css/miestilo.css` ?? Puedes acceder directamente en el navegador usando la url generada??

Comment: Muestra la misma ruta escrita.pero no ingresa a la carpeta **web**. Como si no existiera. Trabajo en el yiiframework basic

Comment: Parece entonces que el fichero no está en la ubicación adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii2 cuenta con funciones como `registerJsFile` y `registerCssFile` para agregar archivos js y css respectivamente,

```
$this->registerJsFile(
  '@web/js/main.js',
  ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]
);

$this->registerCssFile("@web/css/themes/black-and-white.css", [
  'depends' => [\yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset::className()],
  'media' => 'print',
], 'css-print-theme');
```

Te dejo el enlace oficial de yii2 donde explica como usarlos de mejor manera.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html

Comment: No logro solucionar lo siguiente: tengo una pagina principal con otras 10 vistas diferentes cada una. Tengo entendido  que la carpeta web es la carpeta publica.ahi tengo los css. pero no logro que se ejecuten.

Comment: Como lo puse en el ejemplo se registra después del BoostrapAsset, es por eso que es recomendable que leas la documentación, si lo quieres usar trata sin usar dependencias solo $this->registerCssFile("@web/css/miestilo.css"); si vas a usarlo para toda tu página yii te recomienda registrarlo directamente en el archivo asset/AppAsset.php en el array de css

Comment: Pasa lo siguiente,no uso dependencias.al usar el registerCssFile,la ruta es 400. por ende. no esta cargando el css.

Comment: Pasa lo siguiente,no uso dependencias.al usar el registerCssFile,la ruta es 400. por ende. no esta cargando el css(error de ruta).  Estoy usando   $this->registerCssFile("@web/css/micarpeta/miestilo.css");   para cargarlo desde la carpeta publica web/micarpeta/miestilo.css  para usarlos con archivos que estan en layout y site .enrutados ok, pero sin cargar el css.

Comment: A que te refieres con que no estas usando dependencias?

Comment: No estoy usando  bootstrap que esta ubicado en  AppAsset /'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'.Solo estoy usando css creados por mi. no encuentro es la forma que identifique mis archivos. Me ha generado diferentes tipos de errores.

Comment: Solucionado, crear appAssets independientes por cada vista.